# How to rename ruby gem after build is made?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rename

I am trying to push into [rubygems.orge](https://rubygems.org) a simple gem following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler) tutorial. Basically I am using `bundler` and I have write a simple `Hello World` class. Then, I try to push the gem as follows:

```
bundle gem my_first_gem
gem build my_first_gem-0.0.1.gem
```

and I get:

```
Signed in.
Pushing gem to https://rubygems.org...
Repushing of gem versions is not allowed.
Please use `gem yank` to remove bad gem releases.
```

So, I have checked and there is already a gem with such name. So, is there an easy way to rename the gem I have including changing the gem name in all generate by `bulder` files:

[image]

or if I should rename the files by hand, could you tell which are the critical ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of renaming files by hand. As it is just a *tutorial gem*, I would suggest you to create a new gem with

```
bundle gem gotqn_first_gem
```

and just move your `HelloWorld` class in `lib`. And follow the rest of the commands suggested in Railscasts.

Comment: So, generally, before I choose the name of my `gem` I should always check if it is not taken :-)

Comment: Yup..that's the way it works. As there are zillions of gems. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that after renaming you need to call `git add -A` to update your files list.

The reason for that is because (unless that you have changed) your `my_first_gem.gemspec` have a line like that:

```
spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
```

So, when you call `gem build my_first_gem-0.0.1.gem`, the above command will search for your older files and ignore the renamed ones.